# Allow javascript debugger in Play framework (forgotten debugger statement)

Tags: javascript, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using one of the default Play starter templates and I'm trying to do some javascript debugging by placing a

```
debugger;
```

statement in my javascript code.

However, when loading the page, I'm getting a typical Play error page, complaining about this line with:

```
forgotten 'debugger' statement?
```

How can I allow javascript debugging in Play?

Answer (score 1):

Play does not forbid javascript debugging by itself. The reason why this is happening is that the starter templates have the `sbt-jshint` plugin enabled by default, i.e., `project/plugins.sbt` typically contains:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.4")
```

To enable debugging, [JSHint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint) must be configured accordingly. This can be done by creating a file `.jshintrc` in the project directory containing:

```
{
  "debug": true
}
```